# How delete run/test configurations in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

I just moved a directory in my pycharm project that had tests in it. Now the tests fail because the run configuration for them points to the old missing directory. I see I can manually edit each test to use the new directory, but how do I do this all at once, or just delete these runs configurations so that new ones get created with the correct paths? Maybe this is a bug in pycharm? That is, pycharm kept run configurations for the moved tests, but it did not update the paths?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `Run -> Run... -> Edit configurations`

For deletion:

2. On the left, select the configuration you want to delete
3. Click the `-` sign in the top left corner.

For edit:

2. On the left, select the configuration you want to edit.
3. On the right make the modifications you want
4. Click `Apply`

Comment: I have followed these instructions but the deleted configuration reappears when the selected file is re-run.

Comment: @Approaching ??? of course the run configuration reappears when you recreate it by running the file.

Comment: @ruohola When the configuration reappears, it retains the options it had before it was deleted, so that deleting it had no actual effect.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish without more info it's hard to help. It might be best to create a new post since the issue you're not liking is different than the issue in this post. It sounds like you are deleting it, but then re-running. Pycharm needs a config to run so it creates one. Perhaps it's using some default or perhaps its using the last one that existed. Regardless you don't like it. You could create a custom config that DOES do what you want, save it, and then run THAT config. If it's really caching something you don't like maybe clearing caches and restart. If not I recommend a new post